# Storing an input, and printing out a string depending on the input - Java

Tags: java

I have a problem which I have no idea how to solve.

```
               thisPizza = pizzaPick.nextInt();

               if((thisPizza > 0) && (thisPizza < pizza.length))
               {
                orderList[pizzaCount++] = thisPizza;
                sizeMethod();
                System.out.println("\nSubtotal: $" + moneyCounter + "\n");
               }
```

Now, what happens in my program, is that it prompts the user to input which pizza they want, and then at the end, it prints it out. It also asks for the size of the pizza... If they input 1, it'll be large, if they input 2, it'll be small... What I need is so that at the end, it prints out the order (Like in this 'for' statement)

```
    for (int i = 1; i < pizzaCount; i++)
    {
     System.out.println (pizza[orderList[i]]);
    }
```

But then also prints out the size of the pizza (i.e. small or large) depending on which size they chose for each pizza.. So if they chose 1, it would be small, and if they chose 2 it would be large... So the final outcome would be something like:

2- Ham - Large

1- Cheese - Small

10- Italian - Small

3- Bacon - Large

5- Vegetarian - Large

I've already got it working to print out the pizzas, I just need it to print out the size of each, next to it. Thanks!!

Comment: so I dont see any code relating to reading or storing the size. Can you post it? If you are having trouble storing the size with the pizza, I would look at a map like data structure which will associate a pizza to a size, or create a class to read and store both, which might be a better option...I don't have quite enough information to tell. so I'm kinda confused what your coding question is, can you clarify? Also what are the types for orderedList and pizza?

Comment: @pippin1289 Ok, [here's a link to my entire code...](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iyv3ay8w9pzhzw3/HtxvYV--cA/Pizza%20Program.txt)

Comment: What I need is so that the output of the pizza's includes the size for each pizza... The size for each pizza is attained after the user picks a pizza... {It's in whichPizzas under sizeMethod()}.. So, I need some way to store the input for the size of the pizza, for each separate pizza... Is that more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class for your Pizza, then you can handle your output and properties very well (see this sample code). Then for the output just use `System.out.println(myPizzaObject.toString());`:

```
class Pizza {
    String name;
    int size;
    String sizeName;
    ...
    public Pizza(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        parseSizeName(this.size);
    }

    private parseSizeName(int size) {
        switch (size) {
            case 1:
                this.sizeName = "Large"; break;
            case 2:
                this.sizeName = "Small"; break;
        }
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name + ", Size: " + this.sizeName;
    }
```

Comment: Whoooa.. Too advanced... Can you explain what is actually happening so that I can understand? [Here's a link to all of my code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iyv3ay8w9pzhzw3/HtxvYV--cA/Pizza%20Program.txt) if that helps... :) Thanks!

Comment: The class "Pizza" is a template for all the pizzas you will create in the future. You define, what properties and functions (=methods) a pizza contains of. So in this example a Pizza has a name as String, an size value as Integer and a size value as String. The method parseSizeName can transform an Integer size value in the related String representation. The method toString returns a string value with all the information you need, so that you can print it on screen, etc...

Comment: How you can create a pizza? Pizza salamiPizza = new Pizza("Salami Pizza", 1);   How you can print the Pizza on screen? System.out.println(salamiPizza.toString());   ---> Further reading: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/oo.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you just call a method in your `println`statment to get the size of the pizza and return a string with the size. eg.

```
System.out.println (pizza[orderList[i]] + pizzaSize(i))

private String pizzaSize(int i)
{
String large = "large";
String small = "small";

if(sizeArray[i] == 1)
return large;

else if (sizeArray[i] == 2)
return small;
}
```

Sorry if the codes not perfect i'm only learning to but my two cents worth anyway

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean... But how can I actually store the size for each pizza? [Here's a link to all my code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iyv3ay8w9pzhzw3/HtxvYV--cA/Pizza%20Program.txt)... So how can I actually store the int 'size' for each separate pizza?